# Making my sender option to send attachment or not

Tags: php, phpmailer, sender

Anybody have idea what happen with my sender? , trying to make an option to send  attachment or not

```
if ($makassarid_setup['filesend'] == 1) {
$filepdf = file_get_contents($AddAttachment);
$mail->AddAttachment($filepdf);
}
```

Thats are from the MKSENDERS , the sender its self the `$makassarid_setup` came from the mks.setting.php as the config file, its have been included as the top of MKSENDERS file
as u see on `if ($makassarid_setup['filesend'] == 1) {`
it should be sending attachment if i have set 1 on the mks.setting.php file `"filesend"       => 1,` (on mks.setting.php) , but it given me output when im execute the sender

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: AddAttachment in /home/ubuntu/workspace/DEATHhomo/MKSENDERS on line 125
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/ubuntu/workspace/DEATHhomo/MKSENDERS on line 125.
```

when im turn the `"filesend"       => 0,` it send the email normally, without any error input, and the `$filepdf` is came from the mks.setting.php `"filepdf"        => "file/attachment/a.pdf",` so it the filename not empty ofcourse, i would really appreciate any help from you.

Thanks Alot! :D

Comment: hey @JBES can you commend to my script down below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer just needs the filename, not its contents, so it seems you want:

```
if($makassarid_setup['filesend']==1){
    $mail->AddAttachment($filepdf);
}
```

Comment: Hello @JBES , im trying with that but the email send successfully but it doesnt send any pdf file on the email, any solution?

Comment: You mention that `$filepdf` comes from an array in mks.setting.php. Are you sure `$filepdf` contains the correct filename? You can easily `echo "F: $filepdf";` to check. Have you tried replacing `$filepdf` with `$makassarid_setup['filepdf']`?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DUDE!, yes it working with the $makassarid_setup['filepdf'] , struggle this problem all the night without sleeping very make me sick! , thanks alot for the help @JBES god bless you

Comment: You are welcome. Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if ($makassarid_setup['filesend'] == 1) {
            $takeattachmentfromtheconfig = $makassarid_setup['filepdf']
            $callingtheattachmentabove = file_get_contents($takeattachmentfromtheconfig);
            $mail->AddAttachment($callingtheattachmentabove;
        }
```

this is right?